# Send a Jpeg file from an Android phone to server station via a local network

Tags: android, image, base64, jpeg, send

Can i send a jpeg picture from an Android running phone to a server via a local network? Could you people tell me whether this is possible or not? If so, can you explain for me a little about the methodology i should follow?I have heard of base-64 encoder and it works like changing/encoding the picture using base-64 encoder and sending the string file and then decoding it back to a jpeg file on the server and saving it in a folder? After writing some code and trying this method, i have got the quality of image very degraded/becomes low after decoded.What i just exactly want to know is can i send the jpeg file with out making any change, encoding/decoding or other stuffs?Is it possible what method do you suggest me? I would appreciate it if you could point me to some tutorials, blogs, samples along with your suggestion?

Comment: I would like to see if it is possible, because after many research on SO and Google Encoding / Decoding is the best method. And I guess I never found my Image degraded until I told to degrade while encoding. If you need help, we are ready to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you expect the image on server side ... There you can expect to receive the data as Post body (array of bytes) or multipart (pretty much as the other one). This is for Http.

Some links for these:

1. An [Http Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360207/android-sending-a-byte-array-via-http-post) example sending a byte-array. Here's how you can [convert a Bitmap to a byte-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989182/converting-java-bitmap-to-byte-array).
2. Send the Bitmap through a multi-part Post request. A simple example [here](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776104/http-post-high-resolution-image-in-android) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766878/sending-files-using-post-with-httpurlconnection). Haven't looked too much into details on each one, but the implementation is straigh-forward.

Sending through socket or ftp is all about opening a connection, get the output stream and send the converted byte-array on that stream ...